# How to put a str into another str, but on a specific digit in the other str?

Tags: python

(Example:)

```
a = "-"
b = "testtest"
```

I want to put the `a = "-"` after 4 digits of the `b`string (so between the first and second "test").
So it should be always after the first 4 digits (if the `b`-str is longer, it shouldn't just go at the first 4th digit.

Comment: so in the console, it should be "test-test" then (or if it is like 5 "test", should be 4 "-" in between.

Comment: `b[:4] + a + b[4:]`?

Comment: I can't create an answer because the question is closed (which in my opinion is a mistake). I try to post my code here, the formatting will be terrible though. `a = '-'
b = 'testtesttest'
number_of_dashes = (len(b)-1)//4
c = ''
for i in range(number_of_dashes):
    c = c + b[i*4:(i+1)*4] + a
c = c + b[number_of_dashes*4:]
print(c)`

Comment: @Blupper yeah, I also didn't want to close it tho, but it sadly got.. but thanks anyway:D

Comment: @Chaos did the solution I proposed work for you?

Comment: @Chaos, it closed because your question is a duplicate. Use search box on the top of the page.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [slicing](https://realpython.com/lessons/string-slicing/) in a string

```
index = 4
a = '-'
b = 'testtest'
c = b[:index] + a + b[index:]
```

Comment: This works thanks, but also only on the first 4th digit, how can you do it if the b str is for example 16 digits long, and I want every 4th the "-"?

Comment: @Chaos could you update your question for that?

Comment: it is in my question already in tho

Answer (score 2):

```
a = "-"
b = "testtest"

c = b[:4]+a+b[4:]
print (c)
```